# How to remove an annoying zinging noise in an audio track

Tags: audio-quality

I recorded a video and its soundtrack using the Logi Capture software that comes with the [Logitech C920](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920) webcam. In the sound track there's an annoying occasional [zinging](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zing#Verb) noise when I speak into the microphone.

Is there a web site where I can get help cleaning up the audio? I have a brief audio clip to demonstrate the issue if it helps.

I tried the band-pass filter on the soundtrack with Audacity WevPad and it seems to lock the noise frequencies around 3.1 kHz - 5.1 kHz. When I cut this frequency band, the noise disappears. Interestingly, the noise is present when I record sound with either the C920's own microphone or a Samson Q2U USB dynamic microphone. At the same time, when I record with Audacity and the Samson microphone, the noise is not present. So, it must have something to do with the Logi Capture software. I also recorded video with other software and didn’t have this issue with noise.

In my video setup, I'm either capturing the screens or C920 webcam video. For some reason, the video ends up having multiple *audio* tracks. I wonder if it creates an audio track for each computer monitor. One of the *audio* tracks is empty, and the other three are with sound recorded that has this annoying noise.

At the moment, I record a sound track separately with Audacity and replace the one captured with Logi Capture. For already recorded videos I was able to filter out the noise, but it changes the sound of videos a little bit.

Comment: Post the clip. "Zinging noise" is not really enough for us to answer your question.

Comment: where to post it or how?

Comment: You could put it on any sharing service and provide a link. Soundcloud or Youtube for example.